# Python 3 Serial проблема с чтением символов

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyserial

При отправке числовых символов из Терминала с компьютера на RPI через 2 переходника USB - TLL поступает неверный символ. Если просто отправляю с RPI через переходник по кругу и получаю на RPI символ, то результат такой же.

Скорость 9600, 8 бит, parity нет, стоп бит 1.

Программа простая в Python 3:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
 
import serial, time
ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0", 9600, timeout=2, writeTimeout=1)

while 1:
    er = ser.read(1)
    print (er) 

ser.close()
```

Ввожу в терминале 1, получаю g.
Ввожу в терминале 2, получаю 3.
Ввожу в терминале 7, получаю d.

Не нашел решения в интернете. При отправке символа из RPI на терминал, все ок.

Comment: Здравствуйте. Есть подозрение, что вы неправильно передаете аргументы в инициализацию Serial. Попробуйте для начала сделать так:  serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0"). Если все заработает, значит правильная инициализация следующая: serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0", 9600, serial.EIGHTBITS, serial.PARITY_NONE, serial.STOPBITS_ONE, 2, False, False, 1)

Comment: Добрый день. Попробовал без аргументов ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0") на разных скоростях. На скорости 19200 выдает те же результаты, на других скоростях летит мусор какой-то.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решен.
Попробовал перейти с Python 3 на менее привередливый Python 2, но результат оказался таким же. Стало понятно, что вопрос в железе. Поменял USB - TTL переходник на другой и все заработало!

Answer (score 0):

**Я так полагаю ошибка в кодировке**

В зависимости от кодировки посылаемых данных заменяем UTF-8 на нужную:

```
er = ser.read(1).decode("UTF-8")
```

Если нужно прочитать строку а не 1 символ:

```
er = ser.readline().decode("UTF-8")
```